# Add lazy load to page

Tags: javascript, html

My images are loading very slow on my page so I want to add lazy loading to the images, I have organized them like this, I tried to add `img.setAttribute("loading", "lazy");` inside the `function createImageNode(bilde)`   but it didn't do anything

My Js file:

```
const images = [
    
  { fil: "Bff tanquery ikke redigert-11.jpg", class: "img-3"},
  { fil: "Bff tanquery-2.jpg", class: "img-3"},
  { fil: "Bff tanquery-3.jpg",  class: "img-3"},

  { fil: "Bff tanquery-9.jpg", class: "img-2"},
  { fil: "Bff tanquery.jpg", class: "img-2"},


];


function createImageNode(bilde) {
  const div1 = document.createElement("div");
  const div2 = document.createElement("div");
  const img = new Image();
  
  img.src = `img/${bilde.fil}`;
  img.setAttribute("loading", "lazy");

  div1.appendChild(div2);
  div1.classList.add(bilde.class);
  
  div2.appendChild(img);
  div2.classList.add('m2');
  return div1;
}

function addImages() {
  const arrayImagesElement = document.getElementById("arrayImages");
  
  images.forEach((img) => {
    arrayImagesElement.appendChild(createImageNode(img));
    
  });

}
```

This is what I have in html file to get the images on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  addImages();
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't do anything ? are the images inside or close to the viewport ? are you using a browser that supports the loading attribute ? (https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr)

Comment: The problem is that the pages is loading slow, I have around 20 pictures in total. So i tried to add lazy loding so only images in the viewport is loaded not all. I use google chrome

Comment: Have you check the network tab in devtools to check that the images are the bottleneck ? maybe something else is taking too much bandwidth or the server itself could be too slow

Comment: also make sure the images are approximately the size you need them to be, not eg 2000x2000 when you display them in a 100x100 box

Comment: also a big problem with loading="lazy" can be when the viewport is to close. if this is the case the image will be loaded immediately

Comment: Think the problem is the image size, I am making a photograph portfolio page so I want to have nice looking images, every image is now between 4,5 to 5MB...

Comment: honestly it's way too much, even 2MB is too much when you only have one. Put a link to open them full size on them